# How to implement a client that has to login in every 30 min?

Tags: java, design-patterns, junit, singleton, jira

I am writing an application which uses the JiraRestClient by atlassian. I cannot create this client on every Jira interaction so I thought of caching this client.

This client performs login in every 35 minutes so I thought of caching it for 30 min and then perform login again.

For that purpose I need a single instance of this client so that all the threads for the Jira interactions can use it. I created a provider class which will keep the time track and will perform the login, if the creation time of the instance is over 30 min, insuring that the instance is always logged in.

```
public class JiraRestClientProvider {
private static JiraRestClient jiraRestClient;
private static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 1800L;
private static long creationTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();

public static synchronized JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient() {
    if (jiraRestClient == null || Instant.now().getEpochSecond() > creationTime + EXPIRATION_TIME) {
        return createJiraRestClient();
    }
    return jiraRestClient;
}
```

where `createJiraRestClient` is a private method that  reads the credentials, updates the creation time, and updates the private static variable `jiraRestClient`.

Another class uses this `JiraRestClientProvider` class to perform the Jira actions like creating issues or commenting on a issue, etc as follows:

```
JiraRestClientProvider.getJiraRestClient().
getIssueClient().createIssue(issueInput).claim().getKey();
```

or

```
JiraRestClientProvider.getJiraRestClient().getIssueClient()
            .getIssue(issueKey).claim().getCommentsUri().toString();
```

Now, while writing unit test for the class that's using this I can not mock the static method `getJiraRestClient` and therefore unable to write unit tests.
(Also, I cannot use PowerMock).

My question is, is there a way that I can write my provider class such that I will only have single and fresh instance of `JiraRestClient` for all threads and I can also unit test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But not with your design.

Whenever you call:

```
JiraRestClientProvider.getJiraRestClient()
```

you automatically tightly-couple any class with the singleton, which means that every time you call your method under test in unit tests it will call the Singleton. There's no way around that unless of course you want to implement PowerMock :).

A quick win to get this is to wrap your singleton under an interface and use dependancy injection to inject it to your classes.

Writting complete plain code this would look like

```
 interface IJiraClientProvider { 
    JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient();
 }

 class Wrapper implements IJiraClientProvider  { 
    JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient()  {
         return JiraRestClientProvider.getJiraRestClient();
     }
 } 

 class YourClass {  
 private IJiraClientProvider jiraClientProvider
 public YourClass(IJiraClientProvider jiraClientProvider)  {
     this.jiraClientProvider = jiraClientProvider; 
 }

 // now you can unit test your code and mock the dependency  
}
```

When you instantiate `YourClass` you'll have to pass the wrapper:

```
 YourClass cls = new YourClass(new Wrapper());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Thanks;)